# troubles with pyserial and pH meter

Tags: python, serial-port

I am reading the output from a Mettler toledo SevenMulti pH meter. According to the manual I set the baud rate, the parity, the stopbits and databits. The device outputs the data every 3 seconds. Therfore I set the `timeout=3`. However, I receive strange data:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    baudrate=9600,
    port='/dev/ttyUSB1',
    timeout=3,
    parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
    )

ser.xonxoff = 1
ser.rtscts = 0
ser.dsrdtr = 0

data = []
decode = []
line = []
count = 0

while count < 100 :
    data.append(ser.read())
    # line.append(ser.readline())
    count = count + 1

print(data)
ser.close()
```

`data` is like:

```
['K', 'X', '+', '\xb1', ':', '\x02', ' ', '\x02', ' ', 'J', '\r', '\x93', '\xc9', '\xa2', 'p', '\n', '\x92', '3', '\xe9', '\xc2', 'C', '\n', 'Q', 'C', '\xa1', 'H', '\r', 'K', 'X', '+', '\xb1', ':', '\x02', ' ', '\x02', ' ', 'J', '\r', '\x93', '\xc9', '\xa2', 'p', '\n', '\x92', '3', '\xe9', '\xc2', 'C', '\n', 'Q', 'C', '\xa1', 'H', '\r', '', 'K', 'X', '+', '\xb1', ':', '\x02', ' ', '\x02', ' ', 'J', '\r', '\x93', '\xc9', '\xa2', 'p', '\n', '\x92', '3', '\xe9', '\xc2', 'C', '\n', 'Q', 'C', '\xa1', 'H', '\r', 'K', 'X', '+', '\xb1', ':', '\x02', ' ', '\x02', ' ', 'J', '\r', '\x93', '\xc9', '\xa2', 'p', '\n', '\x92', '3']
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong ? The Output should look like `c0H06.00pH`

As suggested, I tried it with `timeout=0` but I do get empty strings. I am going to analyse the analog signal. Maybe there is nothing going through, but why do I receive something if I set `timeout=3` ?

Finally I managed to do it. I had to set the output mode at the pH meter from printer to analog.

Comment: Have you tried to read the data through a serial monitor already? Do you know what the data format is (ASCII, ...)?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think the timeout parameter should be set that way, from the docs "Read size bytes from the serial port. If a timeout is set it may return less characters as requested. With no timeout it will block until the requested number of bytes is read.". I think you should check the port and read data as soon as there are characters to read.

Comment: @albert a colleague of mine did it using the serial library from arduino and got ASCII characters. I tried to convert from hex to ASCII but the output does not make sense.

Comment: For a first try you should remove the `timeout` as suggested by @toti08. I had a look at the [manual](http://de.mt.com/dam/mt_ext_files/Editorial/Generic/1/SevenMulti_Operating_Instruction_Editorial-Generic_1164115415168_files/sevenmulti_v2_51710416d.pdf) and there a different options for the serial port. Are you sure you set those correctly?

Comment: I am pretty sure, I used the correct port. Dmesg tells me the port if I plug the usb in.

Comment: Did you also checked all the port parameters (like parity, stop-bits, etc...)? Sorry, it may sound like obvious...

Comment: Maybe with timeout = 0 you get no result because your while loop ends in less than 3 seconds? I would suggest to put a sleep command after each reading,

Comment: Like @toti08 wrote, double check the serial port settings at the instrument.  The settings are not hardwired, but configurable.  The settings must be identical at both ends of the serial link.  BTW 8 data bits with even parity is an unusual configuration for ASCII text, so I question if that's really *"according to the manual"*.

Comment: This version of a manual, http://us.mt.com/dam/mt_ext_files/Editorial/Generic/1/SevenMulti_Operating_Instruction_Editorial-Generic_1164115415168_files/sevenmulti_v2_51710416e.pdf, has no mention of the `9600 8E1` setting that you're using in your program.  It seems possible to configure the instrument that way, but there's no mention of a default setting.